# Error installing passenger: rake requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0. : Chef recipe error

Tags: ruby, nginx, chef-infra, passenger

I am trying to install passenger gem using chef recipe. Install methos is 'source'.
The ruby version installed is 2.2.3, and the gem binary is also specified as the same version.

But I am getting this error

```
 STDERR: ERROR:  Error installing passenger:
        rake requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

When I tried to install directly in to the test VM it worked without any errors.

Any idea?

**Chef Recipe**

```
if node['nginx']['passenger']['install_method'] == 'package'
  package node['nginx']['package_name']
  package 'passenger'
elsif node['nginx']['passenger']['install_method'] == 'source'

  gem_package 'passenger' do
    action     :install
    version    node['nginx']['passenger']['version']
    gem_binary node['nginx']['passenger']['gem_binary'] if node['nginx']['passenger']['gem_binary']
  end

  node.run_state['nginx_configure_flags'] =
    node.run_state['nginx_configure_flags'] | ["--add-module=#{node['nginx']['passenger']['root']}/ext/nginx"]

end
```

**Test kitchen Log given below**

```
   Recipe: nginx::passenger
             * apt_package[libcurl4-gnutls-dev] action install
               - install version 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.17 of package libcurl4-gnutls-dev

             * gem_package[passenger] action install

               ================================================================================
               Error executing action `install` on resource 'gem_package[passenger]'
               ================================================================================

               Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
               ------------------------------------
               Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
               ---- Begin output of /home/local/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/gem install passenger -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "4.0.57" ----
               STDOUT:
               STDERR: ERROR:  Error installing passenger:
                    rake requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
               ---- End output of /home/local/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/gem install passenger -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "4.0.57" ----
               Ran /home/local/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/gem install passenger -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "4.0.57" returned 1

               Resource Declaration:
               ---------------------
               # In /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/passenger.rb

                39:   gem_package 'passenger' do
                40:     action     :install
                41:     version    node['nginx']['passenger']['version']
                42:     gem_binary node['nginx']['passenger']['gem_binary'] if node['nginx']['passenger']['gem_binary']
                43:   end
                44:

               Compiled Resource:
               ------------------
               # Declared in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/passenger.rb:39:in `from_file'

               gem_package("passenger") do
                 package_name "passenger"
                 action [:install]
                 retries 0
                 retry_delay 2
                 default_guard_interpreter :default
                 version "4.0.57"
                 declared_type :gem_package
                 cookbook_name "nginx"
                 recipe_name "passenger"
                 gem_binary "/home/local/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/gem"
               end

               Platform:
               ---------
               x86_64-linux

           Recipe: postfix::_common
             * service[postfix] action restart
               - restart service service[postfix]

           Running handlers:
           [2018-09-28T20:37:47+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
           Running handlers complete
           [2018-09-28T20:37:47+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
           Chef Client failed. 25 resources updated in 01 minutes 42 seconds
           [2018-09-28T20:37:47+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
           [2018-09-28T20:37:47+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
           [2018-09-28T20:37:47+00:00] ERROR: gem_package[passenger] (nginx::passenger line 39) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
           ---- Begin output of /home/local/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/gem install passenger -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "4.0.57" ----
           STDOUT:
           STDERR: ERROR:  Error installing passenger:
            rake requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
           ---- End output of /home/local/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/gem install passenger -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "4.0.57" ----
           Ran /home/local/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/gem install passenger -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "4.0.57" returned 1
           [2018-09-28T20:37:47+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```